# Why is Modules undefined?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tsconfig

I can't unterstand why `Modules` is undefined.

The Class Modules exists and the path is correct. Any idea?

Here my code:

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import  {Modules} from "modules";

import {
DashboardDemoComponent,
HomeComponent,
AboutComponent,
ApiDemoComponent,
DemoPageComponent,
TableDemoComponent,
FormDemoComponent,
TimelineDemoComponent,
} from 'components';

import {
EmptyComponent,
} from 'components/widgets';

import { MasterdataComponent } from 'masterdata/components';
import {
OrdersTabsComponent,
OrdersListComponent,
OrderComponent,
OrdersListOverviewComponent,
CanDeactivateOrdersTab,
} from 'shop/components';


export class Route{

modules : Modules;

public constructor(){

    console.log(Modules);
    this.modules = new Modules;
}
```

And my paths in `tsconfig.json` looks like:

```
 "paths": { "*": [
  "app/*",
  "modules/*"
]}
```

The modules.ts file is in my folder "modules" and Route in "app"

[here the structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d9JT.png)

Comment: How are you exporting it?

Comment: @SLaks export class Modules { myfunctions... }

Comment: @Igor javascript allows constructor less calls

Answer (score 0):

tsconfig.json "paths" property must be used along with "baseUrl". I'm not entirely sure how your folder structure looks like, but something like this might work:

```
"baseUrl" : "src",
"paths": {
  "app/*" : ["app/*"],
  "modules/*" : ["app/modules/*"],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Importing from a name like that implies that you're importing an npm package (or rather, `node_modules/modules`).

To import a file in your codebase, you need to use a relative path:

```
import  {Modules} from "./modules";
```